# How to get a deflate data from PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, gzip, inflate

I have a very large json (~30mb) that is gzipped with IIS (size is about ~6mb thanks to that). For an unknown reason, gzip works most of the time, but sometimes it doesn't, I have to refresh several time the page before getting the file in gzip.

An user in China seems to never have the file in gzip format and behind proxies and other stuff, load time is just way too long. (He sent me a print screen showing 12mb downloaded in 4 minutes).

The file is generated with php and displayed on the client side with javascript. 
My first (and unique) solution at that time is to gzip by myself the data returned by my query before put in on a file.

I searched and found there are `gzcompress`, `gzencode` and `gzdeflate` on PHP, and most of all gzcompress is supposed to return a `zlib` format so I could use the `zlib` library on javascript.

PHP Side :

```
file_put_contents('data/data2.json',  gzcompress($res, 9));
```

file_put_contents is needed as I refresh the same file every 20 minutes.

Javascript side :

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url:  "data/data2.json",
            headers: { "Content-Encoding" : "gzip", "Content-type": "text/plain" },
            dataType: "text",
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                let inflate = new zlib.inflate(data);
});
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work.

If I write  `let inflate = new zlib.inflate(data).toString('utf8');` like the example it returns `"[Object object]"` and if I removed the toString part it returns `e…s.inflate {}`.

My guess is the encoding between `gzcompress` and `zlib` is not the same (thanks captain) so zlib can't convert but I can't manage to fix it

**TL;DR** Why gzip doesn't work every time? How to compress a json on PHP and decompress it on Javascript?

Comment: The browser usually unzips for you. You don't have to add any logic in javascript.

Comment: @RegisPortalez I'm not sure I tried the right way, I tried with $.getJSON (like I did before) but it returned the binary-whatever-zlib language. I'm wondering if the server gzip the already gzipped file?

Comment: Usually gzip issues come from the server. Enabling it is all about proper server configuration. And yes it looks like your server gzips what you already gzipped with gzcompress (or the other way around).

Comment: @RegisPortalez what could I say to my client to get what doesn't work on my server and on his side (as it works for me) ? Maybe I should post the question in an approch more server oriented?

Answer (score 2):

I would first check that your IIS server is properly configured to [gzip http responses](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpcompression)

After that I'd make a simple request and inspect my network to see if the response is properly gzipped.

Once all of that working good, you can remove the manual php compression

```
file_put_contents('data/data2.json',  gzcompress($res, 9));
```

AND the javascript decompress, since browser will unzip for you, without any extra logic.

Comment: I made all steps and my server was set up correctly. As I mentioned in my question, gzip DOES work most of time. Thanks anyway